# Jquery event identical with Load event in .NET

Tags: jquery

I am more familiar with .Net than languages used in web development but I'm working with a web application.

I have a drop down list that when the user selects other option, checkboxes should appear depending on the option selected. My problem is that, the drop down list has a default option when it is loaded; so there should already be checkboxes. If it is .Net, I will just put my codes for the checkboxes in the Load() event, but how about in Ajax/jquery because I used on("change")? Can anyone help me what is similar to Load event in Ajax/jquery?

Here's my code:

```
$('.select-movie-status').on("change",function(){
        var adStatus = parseInt(this.value);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'db.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {action: 'getMoviesByStatus', id: adStatus},
            success: function(data){
                //alert(adStatus);
                console.log(data);
                var forChk='';  // putting the titles in a checkbox
                for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
                    if(i==0){
                        forChk= '<div class="movieLists"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="data[i].movieID" name="movie_array[i]"> ' + data[i].title + '</label></div>';
                    }
                    else{
                        forChk+= '<div class="movieLists"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="data[i].movieID" name="movie_array[i]"> ' + data[i].title + '</label></div>';
                    }
                }
                $('#movieTitles').html(forChk);
            }
        });
    });
```

And the code for the drop-down list:

```
<select class="half-form select-movie-status" name="section">
                <option class="adStatus" value="1">Now Showing</option>
                <option class="adStatus" value="2">Coming Soon</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Any JS code which is not placed in an event handler will be run on load automatically. Ideally, you should put the code which hides/shows the checkboxes in a function which is then called on load, and on change of the select. If you post the code you have we can show you how to do this.

Comment: Put your code here we will look whats going wrong

Comment: Hello this is PHP not aSp.NeT .

Comment: I already edited my question and put the code. Please do ask if you don't understand my code.

Comment: Yes its PHP, I just want to know what event in PHP/Jquery is similar to the Load event in .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.select-movie-status').on("change",function(){
    var adStatus = parseInt(this.value);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'db.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {action: 'getMoviesByStatus', id: adStatus},
        success: function(data){
            //alert(adStatus);
            console.log(data);
            var forChk='';  // putting the titles in a checkbox
            for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
                if(i==0){
                    forChk= '<div class="movieLists"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="data[i].movieID" name="movie_array[i]"> ' + data[i].title + '</label></div>';
                }
                else{
                    forChk+= '<div class="movieLists"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="data[i].movieID" name="movie_array[i]"> ' + data[i].title + '</label></div>';
                }
            }
            $('#movieTitles').html(forChk);
        }
    });
}).change();
```

That solves it.. It's now working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just trigger the change manually on the document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("select").change();
}
```

PS: [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is like onload method on winform

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/G6Xj8/)

## UPDATE

Based on your updated post, all you need to have is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.select-movie-status').change();
});
```

Comment: @PratikJoshi, he said he already had default selected option, we just need to trigger the event manually..

Comment: Please supply jsfiddle .

Comment: It's working already! Thanks @YuliamChandra.. I've been stuck in this for almost a week already. Cheers!